# I don't see the point of/in doing that

Tags: prepositions, in-of

Please tell me when should I say **Of** and when should I say **In**.

For example consider the sentence below.

> I don't see the point **of/in** doing that.

Comment: The sentence works without prepositions as well. Also, *I don't see **any** point doing that* may also work I guess

Comment: @MaulikV Thank you very much :) So both prepositions are correct in this context and also we can drop the proposition.

Comment: I think *there's no point in doing that.* is more common to express this scenario. There's a song as well ;) http://www.releaselyrics.com/13b7/aubrey-peeples-tell-me/

Comment: @MaulikV Only case where I think "...point doing...." sounds correct is in the sentence "No point doing ...". But in other cases especially in the sentence in OP I think omitting "in/of" sounds incorrect. Also "no point doing ..." is more a conversation, than anything written.

Comment: I agree with @Man_From_India. *I don't see the point doing that.* is ungrammatical. You can't say that.

Comment: @starsplusplus I made the statement, but I really don't have any explanation why. Can you please explain me why it is that only in "...no point verb + ing..." is correct, but not "...point + verb + ing ..." is not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my native dialect, mid-Atlantic American English, here is how it works.

If you want to talk about "the point" and you're talking about an action, use "of" plus a verb.

If you are talking a noun rather than a verb, use "of". Using "in" or no preposition is not correct.

However: if you are saying "any point" or "no point", you can say "in" but not "of," whether you're talking about a noun or a verb, and in some cases you can drop the preposition entirely.

So the following are correct:

> I don't see the point of Stack Exchange.
>
> I don't see any point in Stack Exchange.
>
> I see no point in Stack Exchange.
>
> I don't see the point of posting on Stack Exchange.
>
> I don't see any point in posting on Stack Exchange.
>
> I see no point in posting on Stack Exchange.
>
> There's no point posting on Stack Exchange.
>
> There isn't any point posting on Stack Exchange.

Comment: From your explanation and examples I don't understand whether "I don't see **the** point **in** posting on SE" is correct. You have covered "**the** point **of**" + verb and "**any** point **in**" + verb, but "**the** point **in**" + verb is not clear. Could you please add this case?