# Why is there a preposition in "for several months" but no preposition in "two hours"?

Tags: prepositions

1) The meeting lasted two hours.
2) The drought lasted for several months.
These sentences are from [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/last_4). My question is - Why is there a preposition used in second sentence but not in first?

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21621/why-preposition-is-optional-in-some-cases

Answer (score 12):

In this case the preposition is optional.

> The meeting lasted for two hours.

and

> The drought lasted several months.

are both valid ways to construct the sentences in addition to the versions you posted. The meaning doesn't change.