# He is going to stay quite a long time - why is "for" missing here?

Tags: prepositions

That is from - The faraway tree.

Why is for not necessary there? Will it be wrong if I use for there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a tendency to cut corners where possible. In this sentence "for" is implied and therefore redundant. There is no confusion over meaning. It wouldn't be a problem to include "for", but it's not necessary.

> They've been here (for) a long time

Doesn't require a preposition either.

You might find some useful information in this [similar question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21621/why-preposition-is-optional-in-some-cases).

Comment: Because english doesn't  seem to have fixed rules I find learning it hard. I am confused. How to you learn a language which doesn't have proper rules ?

Comment: Answer: with difficulty. I'm a native speaker but I learn something new every day, and probably will for the rest of my life.

Comment: @Aquarius English has rules. One rule is you don't need *for* in the sentence you ask about. Therefore the *for* is not "missing," as you call it. You also might want to consider shortening your user name.

Answer (score 0):

Normally indications of time length are done with for+time length. "for" can be dropped in indications which are very frequently used.